# unable to send email using php on wamp server

Tags: php, wamp

Below is my email code  written in php,program works fine but i am unable send mail to gmail.
am running my code on wamp server(web server) and am using hmail server(mail server) and squirrel mail(web mail interface)

```
<?php
$to = 'xyz@local.com';
$subject = 'Customer_Details Report';
$msg="php mail";


$result=mail($to, $subject, $msg);
if($result)
{
echo 'your email has been sent';
}
else
{
echo'email not sent';
}
?>
```

Comment: Had you configure SMTP for mail in local?

Comment: i have configured smtp in win32 folder as well as for squirrel mail.but not in php.ini?should i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got hMailer to work with my WAMPServer's PHP

First setup your hmailer server.

1. Create a domain, lets call it testmail.net
2. Create an account that has no password attached to it, lets say nopwd@testmail.net
3. Create an account that is set up as a Catch-all lets say postmaster@testmail.net. Using this you dont have to create an account for every user you want to send mail to and then login as that user, all mail comes to this account.

Now add your mail server domain name to the HOSTS file

Edit c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and add a line like this

```
127.0.0.1  testmail.net
```

If you are running the mail server on another PC use the IP of the other PC instead of 127.0.0.1

Change the php.ini file ( use the wampmanager icon menus to make sure you are editing the correct php.ini )

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = mail.testmail.net
; http://php.net/smtp-port
; assuming you are using the standard port number, change if you used something else.
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = nopwd@testmail.net
```

Now just make sure that you also use the from address when you send mail as the hmailer will want this or it will probably reject the email.

```
$to = 'xyz@testmail.net';
$subject = 'Customer_Details Report';
$msg="php mail";
$headers = 'From: nopwd@testmail.net' . "\r\n"    

$result=mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```